# Can I do this with a template class in c++

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class that is similar to this one:

```
int add(int a,int b)
{
    return a+b;
}
int sub(int a,int b)
{
    return a-b;
}
class C
{
    int m_functionType;
    C(int functionType)
    {
        m_functionType=functionType;
    }
    int calc(int a, int b)
    {
         switch(m_functionType)
         {
            case 1:  // add
               return add(a,b);
               break;
            case 2: // subtract
                return sub(a,b);
          }
     }
};
```

and the use it as follow:

```
main()
{ 
    C add(1);
    C sub(2);
    auto x=add.calc(1,2);
    auto z=sub.calc(2,1);
}
```

This code works, but the function which should be called is resolved at run time, I am looking for a solution that the solves the functions to call at compile time. something such as this:

```
template <int func>
class C
{
   int calc(int a, int b)
    {
         switch(func)
         {
            case 1:  // add
               return add(a,b);
               break;
            case 2: // subtract
                return sub(a,b);
          }
     }
};


 main()
{ 
    C<1> add;
    C<2> sub;
    auto x=add.calc(1,2);
    auto z=sub.calc(2,1);
}
```

Is the above code actually resolves the function during compile time or it still resolve it during run time?

Is there any way that I can do this using a template class?
 Assuming I want to compile it on Visual studio 2013 and GNU which they have some c++11 capability.

Comment: Yes it is possible: C++11 constexpr (or the hard way via 'Expression Templates')

Comment: @DieterLücking Thanks for reply. Can you please give me a sample code or somewhere to read about it. Is it available in visual studio 2013 and GNU ?

Comment: Which function will be called is resolved at compiletime. The compiler can optimize away unused cases from your `switch`.

Comment: Presumably your real code actually compiles successfully?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Answers in comments :( :(

Comment: in the dumbest possible case the switch will still happen at runtime.  In any decent compiler, it will be optimized out and decided at compile time.

Comment: I can't figure out what the `C` class is for.  If you know the operation at compile time, why not just call `add` directly?

Comment: I concur with Mooing Duck. Sure you can do [something like this](http://ideone.com/6GFyk3), but ultimately wouldn't it be easier to just invoke what you want directly?

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks for sample code. This is just a simple example and the idea is to write a class that behave differently based on a template value. in this example, it would simpler if you call them directly, but in other cases maybe you can find a way to do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your example `func` is resolved at run-time in `main`:

```
C add(1);
C sub(2);
```

Compile-time would mean:

```
C<1> add;
C<2> sub;
```

If the change above is acceptable, C++98/03 classic idea is to use function overloads:

```
template <int v>
struct IntToType {
    enum {val = v};
};

int calc_impl(a, b, IntToType<1>) {
    return add(a, b);
}

int calc_impl(a, b, IntToType<2>) {
    return sub(a, b);
}

template <int func>
class C {
    int calc(int a, int b) {
        return calc_impl(a, b, IntToType<func>());
    }
};
```

**Notes:**

1. `calc_impl` are just two functions taking three arguments. The name of the third argument is omitted because it is not used. They are overloaded by third parameter, because `IntToType<1>` and `IntToType<2>` are two different types.
2. You can put `calc_impl` functions into private section of your class for better ergonomics.

Comment: @mans calc_impl are two overloaded (by third argument) functions, you can put them into private section of the class, if you wish.

Comment: @mans It should, if it works with C++03 (in most cases). I was referring to C++03 because there might be more elegant solutions with C++11.

Comment: You did not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of things, you really want to pass the action to be invoked as a template parameter to the outer function that does the invoking indirectly. Depending on your viewpoint, this could be looked at as a policy class or an instance of the strategy pattern<sup>1</sup>.

Since templates are mostly based on types, you usually want to do this with classes rather than functions. Other than that, it's pretty straightforward, though there are a few different possible approaches.

One approach would be to have calc invoke the specified policy in response to its own `operator()` being invoked. Code for that would look like this:

```
#include <iostream>

struct add {
    int operator()(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
};

struct sub {
    int operator()(int a, int b) { return a - b; }
};

template <class C>
struct calc {
    int operator()(int a, int b) {
        return C()(a, b);
    }
};
```

The code to use this could look something like this:

```
int main() { 
    auto x=calc<add>()(1,2);
    auto z=calc<sub>()(2,1);
}
```

Another possibility would be for `calc` to carry out the calculation when the object is constructed, and return the result on demand. That avoids (among other things) the extra set of parens to create an object, then invoke its `operator()` to do the calculation. On the other hand, it means adding an implicit conversion operator from the calculation object to return the result of the calculation, which many people dislike. Code going that route might look like this:

```
template<class C>
struct calc2 {
    int val;
public:
    calc2(int a, int b) : val(C()(a, b)) {}
    operator int() { return val; }
};

// ...
std::cout << calc2<add>(1, 2) << "\n";
std::cout << calc2<sub>(2, 1) << "\n";
```

It's a little hard to say which is really preferable between these two options (and there are other variations as well). Between these, the choice is basically between ugly invocation and ugly implicit conversion.

Of course, depending on what you're doing in the "strategy" part of things, the decision may be simple--if you really need to carry out the action only on demand, instead of immediately upon creation (and saving only the result until needed) the second isn't really an option at all.

I should add that I'm assuming that the integer you're currently supplying to determine what operation to use was an accidental side-effect of the implementation you'd figured out. In other words, I'm assuming that specifying the operation itself more directly as I've done above is really preferable.

---

<sub>1. A strategy is usually an entire algorithm, not something as trivial as adding vs. subtracting, but I'm assuming that's only an example, and your real application does something a little more substantive.</sub>

Answer (score -1):

Which function will be called is resolved at compile-time, because any half-decent modern compiler can optimize away unused cases from your `switch`.